# How can i count how many times a calculation has been run

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm creating a program that takes two inputs, current weight and target weight. Depending on the inputs, it displays different outputs, for example current: 87 and target 64, with 1.38 being the amount of loss per week, i want it to calculate how many times the sum is run until it gets to the current <= target

I've tried to make loops but I dont have enough skill to fully understand how looping works.

```
//Declare basic variables, prompt asks for input from user.
var current = prompt("Please enter your current weight");
var target = prompt("Please enter your target weight");
var weeks = 0; 
var loss = (current - target);
// If 0 is entered by user then the input text will display
if (current <= 0){
    document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
}
// If 0 is entered by user then the input text will display
else if (target <= 0){
    document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
}
else if (target >= current){
    document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
}
// Calculate the weeks it takes to lose weight
else if (current > target){
    loss = (target - current);
    weeks = loss / 1.38;
    document.write(weeks.toFixed(0)); // Displays answer
}
```

I want the expected output of current= 87 and target= 64 to be "17 weeks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to replace the line to avoid negative result:

```
loss = (target - current);
```

with:

```
loss = (current - target);
```

Second, you add the 'weeks' to your output:

```
document.write(weeks.toFixed(0) + ' weeks');
```

```js
//Declare basic variables, prompt asks for input from user.
var current = prompt("Please enter your current weight");
var target = prompt("Please enter your target weight");
var weeks = 0; 
var loss = (current - target);
// If 0 is entered by user then the input text will display
if (current <= 0){
document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
}
// If 0 is entered by user then the input text will display
else if (target <= 0){
document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
}
else if (target >= current){
document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
}
// Calculate the weeks it takes to lose weight
else if (current > target){
loss = (current - target);
weeks = loss / 1.38;
document.write(weeks.toFixed(0) + ' weeks'); // Displays answer
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the general correctness of your code, but if I were to just modify it to re-run over and over again until you have a valid result, and count that, I would do this:

```
var finished = false;
var count = 0;


while (!finished) {
    count++;
    //Declare basic variables, prompt asks for input from user.
    var current = prompt("Please enter your current weight");
    var target = prompt("Please enter your target weight");
    var weeks = 0; 
    var loss = (current - target);

    // If 0 is entered by user then the input text will display
    if (current <= 0){
       document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
    }
    // If 0 is entered by user then the input text will display
    else if (target <= 0){
       document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
    }
    else if (target >= current){
       document.write("Invalid input, please enter greater than 0 kg"); // Displays answer
    }
    // Calculate the weeks it takes to lose weight
    else if (current > target){
        finished = true;
        loss = (target - current);
        weeks = loss / 1.38;
        document.write(weeks.toFixed(0)); // Displays answer
    }
}
```

Use the `finished` variable to track whether or not you should run the loop again, and the `count` variable increments every time it should go through the loop. Set `finished` to true when you get a result you're happy with.

Answer (score 0):

```
function looseWeightEstimator() {
    let weeksToAchieve, currentWeight, targetWeight;
    weeksToAchieve = 0;
    currentWeight = prompt("Please enter your current weight");
    targetWeight = prompt("Please enter your target weight");



    for (let i = 0; currentWeight > targetWeight; i++) {
        weeksToAchieve = weeksToAchieve + 1
        currentWeight = currentWeight - 1.38;
    }
    alert(`It will take ${weeksToAchieve} weeks to achieve your target weight`);


}

looseWeightEstimator()
```